# How to join two columns using 'on' statement if values in each column are not exactly the same?

Tags: sql

I want to join two columns from two different tables where values in column A is not exactly the same as column B. I mean values in column A (which is of type `text`) is part of values in column B (of type `text` as well)

I don't find any SQL operation that fits what I need.

For example: this is a value from column A:

```
'bad-things-gone'
```

And this is the corresponding value from column B:

```
'/article/bad-things-gone'
```

I am using the inner join technique.

```
select 
    articles.title, counted_views.top_counts 
from 
    articles 
inner join 
    counted_views on articles.column_A (operation) counted_views.column_B;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the prefix is always `/article/` you could just `concat()` that.

```
SELECT articles.title,
       counted_views.top_counts 
       FROM articles
            INNER JOIN counted_views
            ON counted_views.column_b = concat('/article/', articles.column_a);
```

If the prefix is variable you could use `LIKE`. It compares strings by simple patterns.

```
SELECT articles.title,
       counted_views.top_counts 
       FROM articles
            INNER JOIN counted_views
            ON counted_views.column_b LIKE concat('%', articles.column_a);
```

`%` is a wildcard for any character.

If there's also a suffix you can append another `%` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are many way to make such a weak join, which are mainly different in performance and from the database vendor.

Some common approaches, and the resulting join condition:

Normalize the strings e.g. by removing all non Alpha chars and only compare this.

```
   ON regexp_replace(upper(column_b),[^A-Z],'') = regexp_replace(upper(column_b),[^A-Z],'')
```

Use database functions which returns the distance between strings (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance]).

```
ON EDIT_DISTANCE(column_b, column_a) < 6
```

Use database functions which only check if string a is included in b.

```
ON contains(column_b, column_a)
```

The above functions like regexp_replace are oracle specific, but similar exists for all major databases.